# From the given figure, prove that $AB=DC$

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, angle

In the given figure,  $AG=FG$, $EG=CG$ and $DC\perp CE$. Prove that $AB=DC$.
[image]

My Attempt 
$$1. \measuredangle GAF=\measuredangle GFA$$
$$2. \measuredangle GEC=\measuredangle GCE$$

I could not get further from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: triangles $\triangle AGF$ and $\triangle EGC$ are isosceles, therefore:

$$
\begin{align}
\angle GAF = (\pi - \angle AGF)/2 \\
\angle GCB = (\pi - \angle CGE)/2 \\
\end{align}
$$

Adding the two equalities, and noting that $\angle AGF + \angle CGE = \pi\,$:

$$
\angle GAF + \angle GCB = (2 \pi - \pi)/2 = \pi /2
$$

Then $\angle ABC = \pi - \angle GAF - \angle GCB = \pi - \pi / 2 = \pi/2$ so $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle, and the center of the circle is the midpoint of the hypotenuse $AC\,$.

Comment: @ dxiv, how is " the centre of circle is the mid point of hypotenuse"?

Comment: Any inscribed right angle subtends a diameter, whose midpoint is the center of the circle.

Comment: @ dxiv, how do I complete the rest?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler Once $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle, it follows that (1) $AB \parallel CD$ since they are both perpendicular to $BC$ so $\angle CAB = \angle ACD\,$, (2) $\angle CDA$ is right since it subtends a diameter. (1)+(2) $\implies$ $\triangle ABC = \triangle CDA\,$ as having all angles and one side equal, therefore $AB=CD\,$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\angle AGF = 2 \angle GCE = 2(90^\circ - \angle ACD)$$, and $$2\angle FAG = 180^\circ - \angle AGF = 180^\circ - 2(90^\circ - \angle ACD) = 2\angle ACD$$, then $$\angle FAG = \angle ACD.$$

So we have $AB \parallel CD$, then $AB \perp BC$, or $AC$ is diameter of the circle. From here you can see that ABCD is a quadrilateral.

Comment: @ GAVD, how is $\angle AGF=2\angle GCE$?

Comment: Because triangle $AGF$ is Isosceles.

Comment: @ GAVD, so how is that? Could you please clarify